# Compare class vector's two function returns with other class vector elements functions

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  void SetName(std::string name) { Name = name; }
  void SetAge(int age) { Age = age; }
  void SetId(int id) { Id = id; }
  void SetNationality(std::string nationality) { Nationality = nationality; }
  //.. other set functions
  std::string GetName() { return Name; }
  int GetAge() { return Age; }
  int GetId { return Id; }
  //.... other Get functions 
Private:
  std::string Name;
  int Age;
  int Id;
  std::string Nationality;
  //... (many other variables)
};
```

Then I have one function where I make and fill vector (`std::vector<MyClass> MyVector`)
This function isn't very important so I didn't write it here.

Then I have function where I use my vector:

```
void MyFun(std::vector<MyClass> vec)
{
  // Now I need to print vector elements Age and Name
  for (std::vector<MyClass>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
    // but if vector has two or more elements which have same Name and Age,
    // I print only the element which has the biggest Id and other elements I 
    // erase from vector
    // if (...) {}          
    std::cout << it->GetName << " :Name; Age: " << it->GetAge << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me with that? 
Important is that, if one of element's parameter(Age or Name), is different, then I print both vector elements name and age. Others variable values don't matter. They can be different or same.

Comment: I have no idea what is going o_0

Comment: If there are duplicate name/age elements, are they going to be next to each other (consecutive), or might they be scattered far apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove duplicates, you can first sort the vector with `std::sort` and then use `std::unique` to remove the duplicates. If the duplicates are already in consecutive elements, you can skip `std::sort` and just use `std::unique`.

To make these work, you need to tell them how to compare the elements.

```
bool less_name_age( MyClass const &lhs, MyClass const &rhs ) {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name? true // ascending alphabetical names
         : rhs.name < lhs.name? false
         : lhs.age < rhs.age? true // ascending ages
         : rhs.age < lhs.age? false
         : rhs.id < lhs.id; // descending order of ID
}

bool equal_name_age( MyClass const &lhs, MyClass const &rhs ) {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.age == rhs.age;
}

std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), less_name_age );
std::vector< MyClass >::iterator new_end
    = std::unique( vec.begin(), vec.end(), equal_name_age );
```

I omitted the getter/setter idiom because life is too short.